# Java - Apache FOP - PDF generated for the second time is corrupt

Tags: java, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using `java - Apache FOP` to generate a PDF and here is the code inside an `execute` method of `struts ActionFroward`.

```
{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    String generatedfile = "generatedfile"+"_"+sessionId+randomGenerator.nextInt(100)+".xml";   
    File file = new File(getServlet().getServletContext().getResource("/ttf/").getPath(),generatedfile);

    FileOutputStream fStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = reportXML.getBytes("UTF-8");
    OutputStream outstream = fStream;
    outstream.write(b);
    outstream = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(outstream);
    String filePath = getServlet().getServletContext().getResource("/ttf/").getPath()+generatedfile;
    xmlfile = new File(filePath);

    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF,  foUserAgent,out);
    Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    File xsltfile = new File(printStylesheetURI.getPath());
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer( new StreamSource(xsltfile));

    Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
    transformer.transform(src, res);
    byte[] pdfBytes = out.toByteArray();
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + generatedfile + ".pdf\"");
    response.setContentType(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF);
    response.setContentLength(pdfBytes.length);
    outstream.close();
    out.close();
    response.getOutputStream().write(pdfBytes);
}
```

The PDF file is generated fine for the first time at the first request with PDF size `22KB`. But for the second request, the PDF is getting corrupted and the size is only `15bytes`. Again for the third request, the file is generated fine with 22KB as file size. Again for the 4th time it fails...

Am I doing anything wrong here? I tried debugging in the local, it is working file for all the requests. But after deploying on the server/environments, I am facing the issue.

Thanks in advance.